# Generating a signal that transforms from sine to rectangular shape using Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, numeric

I want to generate a signal that transforms from sine to rectangular shape with an increasing parameter `f` using Matlab.

For `f = 0`, the signal sould be a sine whereas for `f = 1`, the signal should be a rectangular signal with the same frequency. For increasing values between `0` and `1`, the signal should become increasing similar to a rectangular signal.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to realise that using Matlab. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

My idea was to use the Fourier series of a rectangular signal and - dependent on the parameter `f` - to consider a distinct number of summands of it.

Comment: A simple way is `x = 0:.1:2*pi; y = min(max(sin(x)./(1-f), -1), 1)`. Also, note that with the Fourier series approach you will have the [Gibbs pehenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon), so the result will never resemble a rectangle in a [uniform metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) sense (i.e. there will always be spikes of non-decreasing amplitude)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a purely square wave with period 2π using [`square`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/square.html).

You could do a weighted average of the square wave and sin wave, as an alternative to signal clipping as suggested by Luis in the comments.

```
t = 0:0.1:2*pi;
hold on
f = 0;    % entirely sine wave
plot(t, (square(t)*f + sin(t)*(1-f)))
f = 0.5;  % half and half
plot(t, (square(t)*f + sin(t)*(1-f)))
f = 1;    % entirely square wave
plot(t, (square(t)*f + sin(t)*(1-f)))
```

Output:

[image: wave]